# Android textview not supporting line break

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

I'm creating a custom view programmatically that is displaying text that is parsed from an XML file.  The text is long and contains the "/n" character for force line breaks.  For some reason, the text view is displaying the /n and there isn't any line breaks.  Here is my code:

```
                    // get the first section body
                    Object body1 = tempDict.get("FIRE");
                    String fireText = body1.toString();

                    // create the section body
                    TextView fireBody = new TextView(getActivity());
                    fireBody.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    fireBody.setText(fireText);
                    fireBody.setTextSize(14);
                    fireBody.setSingleLine(false);
                    fireBody.setMaxLines(20);
                    fireBody.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

                    // set the margins and add to view
                    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
                    childView.addView(fireBody,layoutParams);
```

The text from the XML file is like this:

```
Now is the time /n for all good men to /n come to the aid of their /n party
```

It should display as such;

```
Now is the time
for all good men to
come to the aid of their
party
```

Is there are setting that I'm missing?

***UPDATE***

\r\n works if I hard code it into my view. ie:

```
String fireText = "Now is the time \r\n for all good men \r\n to come to the aid";
```

Actually \n also works if i hard code it:

```
String fireText = "Line one\nLine two\nLine three";
```

***FYI***

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

this returns a string of "/n" so there is no need to convert to "/r/n".

Unfortunately, my data originates in a XML file that is parsed and stored in a hashmap. I tried the following:

```
String fireText = body1.toString().replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");
```

The \n is not getting replaced with \r\n.  Could it be because I'm converting from an object to String?

Comment: Line break is \n not /n

Comment: Sorry, typo in my part.  The original text from my XML file is \n.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I've been having the *exact* same problem under the *exact* same circumstances. The solution is fairly straight forward.

When you think about it, since the textview widget is displaying the text with the literal "\n" values, then the string that it is being given must be storing each "\n" like "\\n". So, when your XML string is read and stored, all occurrences of "\n" are being escaped to preserve that text as literal text.

Anyway, all you need to do is:

```
fireBody.setText(fireText.replace("\\n", "\n"));
```

Works for me!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That is the exact solution that I eventually came with.

Comment: replaceAll() use as the first parameter a Regular Expression, replace() use a normal string

Comment: I used replaceAll() and stuck on that about 2 days. you really saved my time.

Answer (score 5):

Tried all the above, did some research of my own resulting in the following solution for rendering line feed escape chars:

```
string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

1) using the replace method you need to filter **escaped** linefeeds (e.g. '\\n')

2) only then each instance of line feed '\n' escape chars gets rendered into the actual linefeed

For this example I used a Google Apps Scripting noSQL database (ScriptDb) with JSON formated data.

Cheers :D

Comment: perfect exactly what i need, i use   string = string.replaceAll("\\n", "<br />"); not working, but your solution working perfectly

Comment: Strange...other solutions are not working but this worked for us.

Answer (score 4):

For line break you use set text view in xml layout this way.

> Now is the time `\r\n` for all good men to `\r\n` come to the aid of their `\r\n` party

Comment: Thanks for the reply. \r\n does work if I hard code the text. ie:

fireBody="Now is the time \r\n for all good men to \r\n come to the aid of their \r\n party"

But, my text originates from a XML file that I parse into a hashmap and just has \n.  I did try:

String fireText = body1.toString().replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");

But my text view still displays the text with \r\n showing and no line breaks.

Comment: Also you can add <br> instead of \n.

And then you can add text to TexView:

articleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textForTextView));

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem and I found a really SIMPLE SOLUTION, if setting the text from an XML resources (I know this is not the same as OP, but its worth to know it)

There is no need to add line breaks manually, just add the text as it is BUT **quoted**.

```
<string name="test_string">"1. First
2. Second Line
3. Third Line"</string>
```

Comment: For the one that downvoted this answer.... I suggest that you try the answer first... Its obvious that you haven't, as it works perfect!

Comment: Works indeed! Tried <br>, \n, \r\n, &#10; but no luck. This was the only way to make it work! The guy that downvoted this answer should be ashamed of himself!

Comment: Wow ... Only this, the simplest of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: But when I add this type of text with enter in database its not working. can you help me? @Corbella

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work on all devices. On some devices the newline separator will still render as some mangled character. But it does look like it works in the layout editor.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fireBody.setText(Html.fromHtml("testing<br>line<\br>")
```

your server need to send `FirstLine<br>lineAfterLineBreak<\br>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My data originates from a XML file that I parse and it would be difficult to reformate for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To force a line break through the XML of your textview, you need to use **\r\n** instead of just **\n**.

So, now your code in the XML becomes

```
android:text="Now is the time \r\n for all good men to \r\n come to the aid of their \r\n party"
```

Or if you want to do it programatically, then in your java code :

```
fireBody.setText("Now is the time \r\n for all good men to \r\n come to the aid of their \r\n party");
```

You can also declare the text as a string resource value, like this :

```
<string name="sample_string">"some test line 1 \n some test line 2"</string>
```

Another easy way to do it would be to change the default attribute of the TextView in your xml file.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContent"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:singleLine="false"

/>
```

And then use, `textView.setText("First line \nSecond line \nThird line");`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've tried replacing the \n with \r\n using:

String fireText = body1.toString().replaceAll("\n", "\r\n"); but the characters are not getting replaced.

Comment: Well, what about this? Put the text you want to display as a string resource value.

Comment: <string name="sample_string"><![CDATA[some test line 1 <br />some test line 2]]></string>

Comment: If you do not want to wish the HTML format, then please check the code in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again for you help.  The text that I need to display is stored in a XML file which I parse into a  hashmap and retrieve using <k,v>.  I have about 80 records and each has a subset of 9-12 fields to display.  I'm creating the textview programmatically as the data varies from one record to the other.  If you look at my original post, I'm setting singleLine to false.  I'm guessing the issue has to do with how I'm parsing from the XML file and storing in the hashmap.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance but I seem to have totally overlooked the singleLine attribute in your code. Well, if it is still not working then I believe that maybe some other issue, maybe something is going wrong in the parsing as you already mentioned. I suggest that you post the code relevant to the parsing on SO and see if it is correct or not.

Comment: And well, this might sound really stupid but did you try running your program on any emulator or device? I mean, there are occasions when the Visual Editor does not display things properly but everything gets rendered properly in the emulator/device.

Comment: No, that isn't stupid. I have tried it both on a vanilla 4.0 emulator and my 2.3.3 device and I get the same results.  I'm thinking that there might be a bug when converting from an Object to a toString.  I will see if I can reduce the parsing code to a reasonable length and post it.

Answer (score -1):

I just Use This and now its Work fine for me

```
 message =message.replace("\n","\r\\n");
```